# Why i am getting can't find module "typescript" when creating an application inside nx workspace in angular?

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, nomachine-nx

I have created an `nx` `workspace` which is successfully generated. Now i am generating a `micro-front-end` app inside that `nx` workspace using this command

```
npx nx g @nrwl/angular:app opShell --mfe --mfeType=host --routing=true
```

So i am getting this error

```
Cannot find module 'typescript'
Require stack:
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\utilities\typescript\compilation.js
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\src\utilities\typescript.js
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\node_modules\@nrwl\workspace\index.js
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\node_modules\@nrwl\angular\src\generators\application\application.js
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\op-mfe\node_modules\@nrwl\tao\src\shared\workspace.js
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\op-mfe\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\lib\init-local.js
- D:\Office\OP-MFE\op-mfe\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\bin\nx.js
- C:\Users\Fahad Subzwari\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nx\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\bin\nx.js
- C:\Users\Fahad Subzwari\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js



OS Details
-Node: 14.7.6
-AngularCLI:12.0.0
```

Current Dirrectory Structure

nx workspace

```
   -opMfe
     -node_modules
     -op-mfe 
       -apps
       -libs
       -node_modules
       -tools
       -nx.json
       -package.json
       -workspace.json
     -package-lock
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "op-mfe",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
   },
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {},
 "devDependencies": {
    "@nrwl/tao": "13.4.2",
    "@nrwl/cli": "13.4.2",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "13.4.2",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

i am running this command `npx nx g @nrwl/angular:app opShell --mfe --mfeType=host --routing=true` at opMfe/op-mfe folder. So it's giving an error which i just mentioned in the beginning.

what can be the issue here?

Comment: Have you installed `node_modules` in your workspace?

Comment: which node_modules?

Comment: In the main directory of your workspace, where the `package.json` is located. Try there `npm install` and try again

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to generate an Angular app but we can see in your `package.json` that you don't have `@nrwl/angular` installed.

Running the following command and try again should fix the issue :

```
npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular
```

See full tutorial on how to setup module federation with angular and nx at https://nx.dev/guides/setup-mfe-with-angular.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Make sure you got a recent `node` installed. I updated to `v16.17.0`, deleted `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json`, did an `npm i` and errors vanished.